# Convolution of element of matrix exponential

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convolution, matrix-exponential, tridiagonal-matrices

I need to take a $d$-dimensional convolution of the last element of a matrix exponential, but am having trouble. Some specifics:

For a positive integer $g$, I have the $g \times g$ matrix

$$
    Q = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & g & & & & & \\
        1 & 0 & (g-1)  & & & & \\
        & 2 & 0 & (g-2)  & & & \\
        & & 3  & \ddots & \ddots & & \\
        & & & \ddots & & 3  & \\
        & & & & (g-2) & 0 & 2 \\
        & & & & & (g-1)  & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Let $0<r<1$, $\hat{x}_g = [0,0,\cdots ,0,1]^T$ be the column unit vector in the $g^{th}$ dimension, and let $H(r)$ be the Heaviside step function, zero for $r<0$. Then define

$$
\tau (r) = H(r)\, \hat{x}_g^T\, e^{Q r}\, \hat{x}_g
$$

$$
\sigma (r) = H(r)\, \hat{x}_g^T\, e^{Q r}\, 1
$$

I.e., the last element of the matrix exponential for $\tau$, or sum of the last row for $\sigma$.

For all positive integers $d$, I need to find the following three quantities:

$$
\left( \otimes_{i=1}^d \tau \right)(r)
$$

$$
\left( \left( \otimes_{i=1}^{d-1} \tau \right) \otimes \sigma \right)(r)
$$
$$
\left( \left( \otimes_{i=1}^{d-2} \tau \right) \otimes \sigma \otimes \sigma \right)(r)
$$

where $\otimes$ denotes convolution. Ideally this would be closed form to use in an infinite sum, but otherwise numerically for a truncated sum.

I've been trying to use the Laplace transform convolution theorem, but I'm having a hard time making it work for arbitrary $g$ and $d$. $g$ only needs to go up to 20 or so, but $d$ needs to go to at least around 100. Also, if anyone knows any good approximations, that could also be super helpful. Thanks!